# Un-Highlight a Web Element in selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, element, highlight

I want to un-highlight a webelement which I had highlighted using Selenium in Java PL. I had highlighted the border of the element using the `JavascriptExecutor` as belows:

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid blue'", searchBtn);
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML for your page?  Any unsuccessful attempts you've made to solve the problem?

Comment: I assume you've tried to set the border style to whatever you'd consider "unhighlighted" using the same syntax as above?  What happens then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the pixel to zero which can just remove the created border around the element `searchBtn`.

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='0px solid blue'", searchBtn);
```

Secondly you also can break your js code to highlight and then use `removeAttribute`
method for the style to remove border

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(
        "arguments[0].setAttribute('style','border: solid 4px red')",
        element);
Thread.sleep(1000);
// highlight
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','')", element);
Thread.sleep(3000);
// unhighlight
js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style','')", element);
```